# Make whole <li> as link vb.net

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, html-lists

I have created a user control that generates list item , how can i make the whole field clickable rather than just a text ( now the hyperlink is wrapped around the merchants name) , wrapping the list in a hyperlink will mess up the entire flow of the table and ive already run out of ideas.

```
 <li>
    <div ID="divmech" class = "hint--top"  data-hint="" runat="server">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypTrendingMerchant" CssClass="merchantName-width"    runat="server" >
    <asp:Label ID="lblMerchantName" runat="server" /> 
    </asp:HyperLink>    
    <asp:Label ID ="lblMerchantDifference" class="gecko-right gecko-trend-arrow pad gecko-col-secondary" font-bold="true" runat="server" /> 
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your div in the link, and make sure it takes up the whole space of your li:

```
<li>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypTrendingMerchant" CssClass="merchantName-width"    runat="server" >
      <div ID="divmech" class = "hint--top"  data-hint="" runat="server">

      <asp:Label ID="lblMerchantName" runat="server" /> 

      <asp:Label ID ="lblMerchantDifference" class="gecko-right gecko-trend-arrow pad gecko-col-secondary" font-bold="true" runat="server" /> 
      </div>
    </asp:HyperLink> 
</li>
```

What you actually wind up doing here will depend on your layout, but something like this.

Comment: I did that too but it would shrink the list item and half of it would appear as a clickable link, the other half stays blank and hyperlink doesnt work

Comment: Without knowing what your layout is, I can't say.  Basically you need to wrap every bit of text that you want to be clickable in your link and make sure that the link takes up the whole width of your li.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypTrendingMerchant" CssClass="merchantName-width" runat="server" >
      <span ID="divmech" class = "hint--top"  data-hint="" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMerchantName" runat="server" /> 

        <asp:Label ID ="lblMerchantDifference" class="gecko-right gecko-trend-arrow pad gecko-col-secondary" font-bold="true" runat="server" /> 
      </span>
    </asp:HyperLink> 
</li>
```

don't put block elements like DIV inside inline elements like A. instead wrap all li content in the link.

then from CSS, make A as block, and if you need the span #divmech as block element, then do that from CSS too. Don't forget to set LI padding to 0 so A element would take most of the space

```
li{
 display:block;
 padding:0;

}

a.merchantName-width{
  display:block;
}

#divmech{
 display:block;
}
```